# Show a specific line depending of a given emojis using Awk?

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I have a file named `emoji.txt` below:

```
 Human 1 Disconnected 
VPN1 Human 2 Disconnected
 Human 3 Is Connected
VPN2 Human 4 Connected
 Human 5 Disconnected
 Human 6 Connected 
VPN4 Human 7 Disconnected
 Human 8 Connected
```

then I hope to get the result like this:

```
 Human 1 Disconnected 
 Human 3 Is Connected
 Human 5 Disconnected
 Human 6 Connected 
 Human 7 Connected
```

At the moment I'm starting with awk, I was able to get only one depending of the given emoji:

```
 Human 6 Connected 
 Human 7 Connected
```

the function:

```
 awk -F"\t" '// {print $0}'  emoji.txt
```

But it's not what i want to do instead of geting only one i want to get all of them i tried

```
 awk -F"\t" '//\/\/\// {print $0}'  emoji.txt
```

But nothing happening.

Comment: So, try `awk -F"\t" '/|||/ {print $0}' emoji.txt`, see [online demo](https://ideone.com/aVkg2a)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your suggestion is not working please check mine, it's working now. Thank you

Comment: No,  `[;;;]` is a wrong pattern.

Comment: It's returning me the right result, is there a problem ?

Comment: `awk -F"\t" '[;;;] {print $0}' emoji.txt` [does not work](https://ideone.com/FbYEkv) at all. `awk -F"\t" '/[;;;]/ {print $0}'` will [output more than you need](https://ideone.com/DVj1jM)

Comment: Please place answers in Answer blocks. Later, you can accept your own Answer. Also see [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/173448)

Comment: Your posted expected output doesn't match your posted sample input. See the "Human 7" line in both - input doesn't start with an emoji but output does.

Comment: Also clarify if you're looking for a script that prints **all** lines that start with **all** emojis, or just specific emojis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use an alternation in the awk pattern:

```
awk '/|||/' emoji.txt
```

Note that `;` inside bracket expressions are treated as literal symbols.

Emojis are multibyte code points and using them inside bracket expressions may yield unexpected output, thus an alternation is preferred.

Also, `{print $0}` is the default action, hence you may omit it. As you are not using the field separator later, thus, `-F"\t"` is also redundant (as records are split into fields with any horizontal whitespace characters by default).

Comment: thank you sir now it's more clear, I apologize for abusing your kindness. is it possible to tell me how to sort them by emoji ? with this way they can be regrouped

Comment: @StillLearningHowtodoit Just use `sort`, doesn't it work?

Comment: the problem is caused by some line the emoji may have space after him and sometimes it's one word   Human is not  Human is not Human